# How do you show dynamic messages on custom actions?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a working custom action set up like this in the share-config-custom.xml

```
<action id="deploy-asset-qa" type="javascript" label="Deploy File to QA..." icon="document-move-to">
    <param name="function">onActionSimpleRepoAction</param>
    <permissions>
        <permission allow="true">Write</permission>
    </permissions>
    <param name="action">deploy-asset-qa</param>
    <param name="successMessage">message.deployment-success-qa</param>
    <param name="failureMessage">message.deployment-failure-qa</param>
</action>
```

This works great, but this only shows the hard coded messages if it was a success or a failure.

I would like to present the user with more dynamic error messages that give good feed back.

How do you show dynamic messages on custom actions?

I am using Alfresco Community 5.0.d

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic message?

Comment: The param for both successMessage or failureMessage points to a properties file value that displays a static text in a small popup. Currently they say "Deployment to QA was successful" or "Deployment to QA Failed" but I would like to show a more descriptive message saying why it failed to help the users out.

Comment: @MJSalinas Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @kgthegreat nope, a coworker went the route of creating a dynamic html that then pops up after process runs. It shows details for either case.

Comment: @MJSalinas Thanks for the response. I assume that the dynamic html is being rendered from the js callback method specified in the action declaration in the relevant xml?

Comment: @kgthegreat yes, that is exactly it. I still don't feel that it is the best of solutions, but it does give us great customization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Try below steps. I am giving generic scenario that you can apply in your case.

```
1)From Share UI, I click on custom action
2)This action will call your Repo data webscript to check datatype OR whatever is your logic.
3)You can define specific Success/Failure message as part of your data webscript's JSON response.
4)You can access this response and so this custom message in Share client side js
5)Display this message to users.

For Failure I would suggest You can add, specific template file with failure status code and Failure message.
Ex: customAction.get.json.500.ftl  , customAction.get.json.400.ftl etc..

Hope it helps!
```